# Scale VBO magnitudes based on aspect ratio

Tags: vbo, aspect-ratio

On my screen I have drawn a box. When I adjust my screen size (to a non 1:1 aspect ratio) I get a rectangle. This is obviously something wrong with my projection matrix.

I am attempting to keep everything in my engine scaled from 0->1 to make it simple to define assets and have them look good on any size screen.

I would like to make my internal VBO sizes scale with the window's aspect ratio. In this example I have one asset that I define as having a width and height of "0.01" which is 1/100th the screen size.

I create the following VBO with this...

```
    GLuint VAO, VBO, EBO;
    GLfloat verts[] = {
            width, height, 0.0f,
            width,   0.0f, 0.0f,
             0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,
             0.0f, height, 0.0f
    };
    GLuint idxs[] = {
            0, 1, 3,
            1, 2, 3
    };

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(idxs), idxs, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), NULL);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
```

I'm using an ortho matrix from (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), I'm correclty doing my [PVM multiplication in my shader](https://github.com/gravypod/solid-snake/blob/master/game/assets/shaders/shared.vert#L10), and I've correctly translated my matrix.

My boxes are still rectangles and I believe that this is because my original "1/100th" screen size is different from my new screen's width and height. How do I correctly scale my width and height that I've given to my VBO?

Edit: PS you can find all of the important pieces of code in my git repo (https://github.com/gravypod/solid-snake/). I'd link directly to the right section but StackExchange seems to have a karma based limit...

Answer (score 1):

You need to recalculate your projection matrix whenever the screen aspect ratio changes.

1/100th of the screen width and height is still exactly 1/100th of the screen width  and height when the viewport is rectangular but now that will be a rectangle.

What you need to do to keep your coordinate units square is decide if you want to shrink to square or expand to square (or something in between) and which direction and then generate a projection matrix that will have a different width scale than height scale.

So for example, when your screen is 16:9 your ortho matrix range could be (-0.388888889, 1.388888889, 0, 1, 0, 1) = shrink, or (0, 1, 0.21875, 0.78125, 0, 1) = expand to keep everything square.

You take the aspect ratio (eg: 16:9) which is **width/height** and apply that to either the X range or the inverse of it (eg: 9:16) to the Y range of your ortho matrix.

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to limit, lets say, generate a set of VBOs for every aspect ratio and choose the right one for the right aspect? I'd like to figure out a way to just support more than one aspect ratio. I'd be happy to get that working.

Comment: @JoshuaKatz - how do you know what every possible aspect ratio is? What if a new device with a different aspect ratio is released? Far simpler to just adjust the projection matrix.

Comment: @LeComteduMerde-fou how do I do that? I detailed my efforts in my post. Is there something I've missed? How do I scale my projection matrix by the apsect ratio?

Comment: @JoshuaKatz - that's what this answer is telling you how to do.

Comment: You take the aspect ratio (eg: 16:9) which is width/height and apply that to either the X range or the inverse of it (eg: 9:16) to the Y range of your ortho matrix.

Comment: @StephaneHockenhull that will shrink (2nd image) my viewport, right? I'll give that a try. Is there a way to effectively just expand my viewport. For instance if my old viewport was 0->1, 0->1 and my new viewport is now .5 bigger on the X scale can I just change my new viewport to -.25->1.25? Does anyone have an example of this or a reason as to why this is a bad idea?